# How to remove a MapType from google map using Google Maps Javascript V3 API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is the snippet I am using to display Google map on my app using their V3 Javascript API.

```
var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

But the map shows terrain, hybrid and satellite which I don't want. How do I remove those controls from the map.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can [remove all the default UI](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DisablingDefaults)

```
var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

And then you can [add your own controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map)

Or you can just add  `mapTypeControl: false`

Answer (score 16):

[The Google Maps v3 API doc](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) is great.

In it, you'll find that [MapOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions) have a property, "mapTypeControl", which is a boolean. Set it to `false` to disable it for your map.

Answer (score 3):

To disable only map control, use this option in [Gmap3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapOptions) :

> mapTypeControl
>   Type:  boolean
>
> The initial enabled/disabled state of the Map type control.

example:

```
var options = {
   // ...
   mapTypeControl: false
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
```

Answer (score 2):

So there's no URL attribute for disabling the satellite/terrain maps from Google's own embed code?

Comment: So, this question is about the JavaScript API, which presumes you'll have a script tag with the `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js`at the start of its source attribute. You can pass the callback=<functionName> parameter to specify a javascript callback function. That should let you set the `disableDefaultUI` attribute of the map object.